# double quote inside mysql script not working

Tags: mysql, bash, double-quotes, cron-task, quote

I want to create a cron script for my FreePBX. If I connect from terminal to mysql it works this way:

```
mysql -u user -ppasswd table
UPDATE kvstore SET val='$HOST' where `key`="externip";
```

but inside a script like this:

```
mysql -u user -ppasswd table  -e "UPDATE kvstore SET val='$HOST' where `key`="externip";";
```

it returns me:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '=externip' at line 1
```

For instance I have this script with no problem because have no double quotes inside the script:

```
mysql -u user -ppasswd table -e "UPDATE sipsettings SET data = '$HOST' WHERE sipsettings.keyword = 'externip_val' AND sipsettings.seq = 40 AND sipsettings.type = 0;";
```

I tried all the ways I can putting \" for the quotes but no way to find the solution.

Thanks for your answer if anyone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

The embedded double quotes do clash with the surrounding double quotes. In SQL, it is generally a good practice to use single quotes to define strings anyway, so I would recommend:

```
mysql -u user -ppasswd table  -e "UPDATE kvstore SET val='$HOST' where `key`='externip';";
```